# Simplifying $ \frac{3\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}} \div 2a^{3/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I've been struggling for a while to answer this math question given to me, it reads:

> Simplify this into both radical and exponential form:
> $$ \frac{3\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}} \div 2a^{3/2}$$

I've tried to rationalize the denominator, though I am unsure if I should times $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}$ to only
$\dfrac{3\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}}$ or the whole equation $\left(\dfrac{3 \sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}} \div 2 a^{3/2}\right)$.

So it's stumped me to figure out what to do now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing should be cleared up before you can answer this. Do you mean $\frac{3\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}} \div \left(2a^{3/2}\right)$? By the standard order of operations, you have $\left(\frac{3\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}} \div 2\right)a^{3/2}$. And these are not the same.

Comment: I am assuming $a>0?$ I suggest converting everything to exponential form, simplifying, and at the very end obtain the radical form

Comment: I'm concerned that $3\sqrt{a^2}$ may be actually $\sqrt[3]{a^2}$. (otherwise the calculation is a little unnatural.)

Comment: @aerile I don't think so, it shows to be $3\sqrt{a^2}$

Comment: @DavidP I'll attempt to do so, and see if I can get any farther then.

Comment: Square it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found an answer.

I started from exponential form and then converted it into radical form.

So I converted everything from

> $\frac{3\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt{3}} \div 2a^{3/2}$

to

> $\dfrac{3{a}^{\frac{2}{2}}}{{3}^{\frac{1}{2}}}\div2{a}^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Then I simplify even more by changing the division sign for $\div2{a}^{\frac{3}{2}}$ into $\times\dfrac{1}{2{a}^{-\frac{3}{2}}}$

Making this whole equation look like now

> $  \dfrac{ 3 { a  }^{  \frac{ 2  }{ 2  }    }    }{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 1  }{ 2  }    }    }   \times   \dfrac{ 1  }{ 2 { a  }^{ - \frac{ 3  }{ 2  }    }    }   $

And then merge the two:

> $\dfrac{ 3 { a  }^{  \frac{ 2  }{ 2  }    }   \times  1  }{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 1  }{ 2  }    }   \times  2 { a  }^{ - \frac{ 3  }{ 2  }    }    }$

And since we shouldn't have the negative exponent in the denominator we move it up to the numerator changing its exponent from a negative to a positive. And will make

> $  \dfrac{ 3 { a  }^{  \frac{ 2  }{ 2  }    }   \cdot   { a  }^{ 
> > \frac{ 3  }{ 2  }    }    }{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 1  }{ 2  }    }  
> > \times  2  }   $

into

> $  \dfrac{ 3 { a  }^{  \frac{ 5  }{ 2  }    }    }{  { 3  }^{  \frac{
> > 1  }{ 2  }    }   \times  2  }   $

And finally, we can express the 3 in the numerator as $  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 2  }{ 2  }    }$, so

> $  \dfrac{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 2  }{ 2  }    }   { a  }^{  \frac{ 5  }{ 2  }    }    }{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 1  }{ 2  }    }   \times  2  }   $ becomes $  \dfrac{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 1  }{ 2  }    }   { a  }^{  \frac{ 5  }{ 2  }    }    }{ 2  }   $

Now the answer is in exponential form.

And to change it into radical form isn't too hard of a task either.

It is simply changing

> $  \dfrac{  { 3  }^{  \frac{ 1  }{ 2  }    }   { a  }^{  \frac{ 5  }{ 2  }    }    }{ 2  }   $

Into

> $  \dfrac{  \sqrt{ 3 \left(  { a  }^{ 5  }    \right)    \phantom{\tiny{!}}}    }{ 2  }   $

But, nonetheless, I think I've reached the answer. Thank you to everyone who guided me in this question.

Comment: $\div2{a}^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is the same as $\times\dfrac{1}{2{a}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$